# How send function works

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, send

I am using `ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);` from `socket.h` file. I have some doubts about it.

**Doubt 1**:If suppose the string I am passing to `send` is of length `10` and the length i specified in the third parameter is `15`. Then what will `send` only send 10 chars or it will send 15 chars (which it gets by reading unallocated memory for last 5 chars).
What will happen in the reverse case means if length of second parameter is more than third parameter.

**Doubt 2**:I am assuming the length of second parameter is equal to third parameter. Now if the second parameter is say - `"abc\0def\0qw"`. Its length is 11. Will `send` send the whole string or `\0` have any of its effect. I think it will send the whole string. How really send works.

If someone know any good source about `send`, `recv` which discuss these function in depth pls share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `send` function knows nothing about "strings".  If you give it a pointer, and tell it to send the next 15 bytes after that pointer, then that is *EXACTLY* what it will try to do.  (You may well encounter a **Seg-Fault** or similar if you give it an inappropriate `len` value).

There is no justification for believing that it would stop just because it finds a byte with value `0x00`.  After all, many network protocols are FILLED with `0x00` all over the place.  You can't have `send` stopping every time it happens to find that value.

Answer (score 2):

- The function `send` will try to send exactly as much as you tell it. If the buffer is big enough, nothing special happens. If it's not, what does happen is not defined: it could send garbage or it could crash or it could do anything else
- The function `send` does not care about buffer contents - it only cares about the specified number of bytes to write

Answer (score 1):

`send` doesn't know anything about NUL-terminated strings (there's a clue in the parameter types - it takes a `void*` rather than a `char*`).

It simply sends the number of bytes you give it, from the address you give it.  If that means reading unallocated memory, then that's what it'll do, possibly crashing in the process.